# PGP key armored encoding in Go's openpgp package

Tags: go, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to print a PGP public key in an ASCII armored encoding using Go's `openpgp/armor` package.

The output I would expect:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

<base64 encoded bytes of public key>
<checksum>
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The output I get:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

<first part of base64 encoded bytes of public key>
```

It only prints the first part of the public key.

The public key is obtained from a local keyring file and processed as follows:

```
keyRingFileBuffer, err := os.Open(keyRingFilePath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer keyRingFileBuffer.Close()

keyRing,err := openpgp.ReadKeyRing(keyRingFileBuffer)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, k := range keyRing {
    w, _ := armor.Encode(os.Stdout, openpgp.PublicKeyType, nil)
    k.PrimaryKey.Serialize(w)
}
```

Am I using the package incorrectly? Any ideas on how to track the reason for this (in my opinion) wrong output?

Comment: While I found the answer myself, I'd love to give the bounty to anyone who finds a cleaner answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoops, after putting a bounty on the question I found an answer. Oh well.

The `armor` writer must be closed in order to add that end line.

```
pubKeyBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
pubKeyWriter, err := armor.Encode(pubKeyBuf, openpgp.PublicKeyType, nil)
checkIfError(err)
err = e.Serialize(pubKeyWriter)
pubKeyWriter.Close()
checkIfError(err)
```